# Injecting JavaScript into UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, javascript-injection

I am trying to use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to alter a WebView and it's not executing as I expect.

Here is the code, this JS doesn't execute though. Any idea why?

```
UIWebView *wv = [UIWebView alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

[wv loadRequest:request];

[wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.write('This Works')"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you'll have to wait for the request to finish before you can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. Set `wv.delegate = self;` and then implement `-webViewDidFinishLoad` like this

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.write('This Works')"];
}
```

Comment: After I try this, the WebView goes blank and I can't see "This Works" anywhere.

Comment: @Andrew Barinov, If you need to stop it, use a boolean flag. If you want to write a text to google search field, document.write is not what you are looking for.

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. Your delegate methods are getting called properly, right?

Comment: Yep, I put an NSLog into my delegate method and I see it printing on my console.

Comment: @user792677 I'm actually trying to modify the structure of the page the user sees, not perform a search.